# How to parse Json with jq?

Tags: json

I tried this

```
jq -r '.[0]' my.json
```

Got error

```
jq: error (at ticr_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-01-30.json:139): Cannot index object with number
jq: error (at ticr_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-01-30.json:140): Cannot index object with number
jq: error (at ticr_calculated_3_2020-05-27T11-01-30.json:141): Cannot index object with number
```

With

jq '.' my.json
Output

```
{
  "code_event": "2358562|265|",
  "code_event_system": "STATIC",
  "company_id": "3",
  "date_event": "2020-03-14 17:20:00.000",
  "date_event_real": "0001-01-01 00:00:00.000",
  "ecode_class": "265",
  "ecode_event": "4804",
  "eperiod_event": "",
  "etl_date": "2020-05-27",
}
```

With pipe

```
jq '.' my.json | '.code_event'
```

I got

```
zsh: command not found: .code_event
```

With `jq '.' my.json | wc -l`
141

What Hans suggested

```
jq '.code_event'

"2378270|271|"
"2378265|271|"
"2378272|271|"
"2283936|266|"
"2283938|266|"
"2044564|265|"
"2044560|265|"
"2044559|265|"
"2044556|265|"
"2358047|265|"
"2358050|265|"
"2358562|265|"
```

How to parse Json by "code_event"? My goal is to get the first one firstly.

Comment: your json is corrupted, there is an unnecessary comma on line 10, strictly speaking json doesn't allow it (it's legal in JavaScript but not JSON, some JSON parsers does allow it, but jq isn't one of them) - also `jq ".code_event"`

Comment: @hanshenrik I cut it short. Will edit my question.

Comment: maybe `.[0].code_event` ? still, you are clearly not providing enough of the json to reproduce the issue..